# Eclipse RCP application: e4 or not?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm new to Eclipse RCP development and just built an initial prototype application on e4, because e4 tutorials are the first to shown on Google and it seems to the be recommended API. But now after the very basic functions are completed, I found that nobody seems to be mixing e4 with anything in Eclipse IDE itself - such as preference dialog, perspectives list UI etc - if there is anyone using e4 in real-world projects at all. I checked the source of Luna and then realized that basically all features are still implemented on old 3.x API.

So what should I do now? While it's still possible to continue with e4, there are no more examples other than those in platform source, and no more book (I bought the only one) or practical tutorials covering topics such as integrating with editor or outline. Or I could just give up now and re-make everything with old API - but what would I lose?

Comment: Sorry but this way to broad for a SO answer. The core of Luna is the e4 API but with a very large compatibility layer on top of that to provide the 3.x API. If you don't want to use Eclipse IDE code you can use e4 otherwise you have to stick to the 3.x API (with some e4 features available).

Comment: I do need a lot of Eclipse IDE code, things like preference-page and perspective management are critical. Anyway, I ended up rewriting all code by v3 API and now it works just as I had expected.

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/eclipse-4-plug-development-example-beginners-guide is a good overview of what can be done with e4. Two things you'd loose using the old API are dependency injection (really helpful) and ability to use a different renderer (eg JavaFx instead of SWT - though for production ready implementation may need to wait for Mars?)